# convert sass to scss

Tags: sass

Hi I have this sass mixin and id like to change it to SCSS mixin im really close can anyone help?

```
SASS
=animate($name: fadeIn, $duration: 1s, $delay: .2s, $function: ease, $mode: both)
  +experimental(animation, $name $duration $delay $function $mode)

What iv done so far in SCSS
@mixin animate($name, $duration, $delay, $function, $mode) {
animation: {
  name: $name; 
  duration: $duration; 
  delay: $delay; 
  function: $function; 
  mode: $mode;
 }
}
```

Comment: If you're just looking to switch between SASS and SCSS syntax, there is a command line tool that comes with Sass that will do it for you:  `sass-convert filename.sass filename.scss` (or `sass-convert filename.scss filename.sass` for the reverse).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am thinking this is what you are trying to do.

**MIXIN:**

```
@mixin animate($name, $duration, $delay, $function, $mode) {
   name: $name; 
   duration: $duration; 
   delay: $delay; 
   function: $function; 
   mode: $mode;
}
```

**INCLUDE:**

```
// SELECTOR TO ADD ANIMATION TO
.animation {
    @include animate(fadein, 1s, .2s, ease, both);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

SCSS =

```
@mixin animate($name, $duration, $delay, $function, $mode) {
   name: $name; 
   duration: $duration; 
   delay: $delay; 
   function: $function; 
   mode: $mode }

.animation {
    @include animate(fadein, 1s, .2s, ease, both) }
```

CSS =

```
.animation {
  name: fadein;
  duration: 1s;
  delay: 0.2s;
  function: ease;
  mode: both; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try out this:

```
@mixin animate($name: fadeIn, $duration: 1s, $delay: 0.2s, $function: ease, $mode: both) {
    @include experimental(animation, $name $duration $delay $function $mode);
}
```

Comment: Do not bump old questions unless you have something meaningful to add.  This answer adds nothing over the existing answers and does not compile as is.